# Autofill Watch data with values when debugging in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

When I debug my web project I start with an empty Watch window and I have to add all data myself.

When a friend of mine showed me how to debug with Visual Studio he got all Watch values automatically filled in the window.

How do I get my Visual Studio to autofill my Watch window with all available values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend might have shown you the [Locals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6td98xe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) window or the [Autos](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=visual%20studio%20autos%20window&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290702%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=8UrfTqmtI5HCswar2PDMCA&usg=AFQjCNGoi_9eupU47ngpKHD0etHXGukOog) window. They are both available through the Debug window, and automatically show you the relevant variables. The Watch window, on the other hand, is supposed to come up empty and let you fill in expressions by yourself.